# ssl issue with google chrome and css on aceshop/joomla

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, joomla, https, aceshop

I have a joomla installation which I have installed aceshop onto. I have also setup an SSL for the checkout page as that is the only area I want or need to have secured for ssl.

The problem im getting is with Google Chrome. Because the checkout page is in SSL, and the css/js references aren't, Chrome is blocking the css. You have to override the security setting for the page to display it properly.

Anyone know how to fix this problem? I DON'T want the rest of the site under sll, just the checkout page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serve your CSS/JS over SSL as well. If you don't, it doesn't matter that you have served the page over SSL. In that case, a man-in-the-middle attacker can add arbitrary JavaScript, which will execute in the context of the checkout page, where it can steal all the information that the user types (name, address, cc, whatever).

If you want your site to be secure, you need to fix all the mixed mode content problems, otherwise it is equivalent to having no security at all.